# How to get multiple v-for values inside a b-form-select in VUEJS

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to get values for the `b-form-select` from an array inside the array but not able to get it.
I have a code like this:

```
        <span v-for="(user, index) in Users" :key="index">
          <span v-for="(userName, index) in user.details" :key="index"> {{userName.name}}</span>
        </span>
```

I am getting the `user name` here, but I want to display it inside an `b-form-select`.

I have a code for the `b-form-select` but it is not helping.

```
        <b-form-select
              v-model="user_name"
          >
            <option
                :value="userName.id"
                v-for="userName in Users.details"
                :key="userName.id"
            >{{ userName.name }}
            </option
            >
          </b-form-select>
```

ANy solution to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code on top is iterating over `user.details` from a `Users` array while the second code block is iterating over `Users.details`. Do you spot the difference? If you want to iterate over **all** `details` you'd need to collect them from `Users` first. For example,

```
const details = Users.map(user => user.details)
```

Or else grab the user you want from `Users` and iterate over `user.details` the same way as you do in the spans.